# Telegram bot api - getUpdates does not igonre deleted messages

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm working on **Telegram Bot API** and I want to implement some features in my application. At this time, **I need to get last NON deleted channel message via a bot.** For this purpose, I have created a bot and set it as an administrator of that channel, and call [`getUpdates`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) method of official api. For calling this method, I have provided bot `token`, and set `offset: -1` and `limit: 1`. This returns me the last message. But my problem is **even if I delete last message, api still returns deleted message.** How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I am running into the same issue, curious if you were able to figure out a way?

Comment: @user1596115 No, I don't know why, but telegram policy is not ignoring deleted messages! I found telegram official bot support, you can ask this question from him. Telegram username: @ BotSupport

Comment: thanks man, appreciate the reply!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late, but: I think this is how it should be. The telegram `getUpdates` is only for checking if there are new updates. Message deletion doesn´t count as an update that´s why you get the deleted update. Sadly there is no attribute to check if the message is already deleted...

Maybe you could think of using a webhook as alternative or somethink like that?